# Binding object to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I'm trying to control the state of child UserControls from my main UserControl. I was thinking of achieving that by creating a DependencyProperty object in Parent UC and referencing it in XAML when creating Children UCs.

The problem is, I get NullReferenceException in Step.xaml.cs (Child code behind) with everything referencing Controller property, first being StepEnabled property. When I leave out the XAML binding and let it instantiate in constructor, it's ok, though I can't of course control anything, but the way it is Controller property always goes null... Code follows:

ParentViewModel:

```
public class ParentVM : NotifyPropChanged
{
    ...

    public StepController Step1 = new StepController();
    public StepController Step2 = new StepController();
    public StepController Step3 = new StepController();

    public ParentVM()
    {
        ...

        GetReady();
    }

    public void GetReady()
    {
        Step1.Clear();
        Step2.Clear();
        Step3.Clear();

    }
```

StepController:

```
public class StepController
{
    public bool StepEnabled;
    public bool? WasSuccessful;

    public StepController()
    {
        Clear();
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        StepEnabled = false;
        WasSuccessful = null;
    }
}
```

Child (code behind):

```
public partial class Step : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty ControllerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Controller", typeof(StepController), typeof(Step), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public StepController Controller
    {
        get { return (StepController)GetValue(ControllerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControllerProperty, value); }
    }

    ...

    public bool StepEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)Controller.StepEnabled; }
        set { Controller.StepEnabled = value; }
    }
    public bool IsDone
    {
        get
        {
            return (Controller.WasSuccessful != null);
        }
    }
    public bool? WasSuccessful
    {
        get { return Controller.WasSuccessful; }
        set { Controller.WasSuccessful = value; }
    }

    public Step()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        ...

        Controller = new StepController();

    }

}
```

ParentUC:

```
...
<local:Step Controller="{Binding Path=Step1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
...
```

ChildUC:

```
e.g.:
<TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding StepEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I'm pretty new to WPF and am still unsure about whole lot of things like DataContext and such, so I guess I'm missing something obvious... Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You are missing NotifyPropertyChanged and you should be using properties instead fields in the StepController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Synapse already mentioned your `DependencyProperty` inside the `Step`-`UserControl` should instanciate a default value for your `StepController` class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ControllerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Controller", typeof (StepController), typeof (Step), new PropertyMetadata(default(StepController)));

    public StepController Controller
    {
        get { return (StepController) GetValue(ControllerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControllerProperty, value); }
    }
```

Your ParentUC should look like this (DataContext only set here for example):

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StepControllerExample" x:Class="StepControllerExample.ParentUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ParentVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
    <local:Step Controller="{Binding Step1}"/>
    <local:Step Controller="{Binding Step2}"/>
    <local:Step Controller="{Binding Step3}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Your Child UserControl XAML like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="StepControllerExample.Step"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock"/>

    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Controller.StepEnabled, ElementName=userControl}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

Your Child UserControl CodeBehind like that:

```
public partial class Step : UserControl
{
    public Step()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControllerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Controller", typeof (StepController), typeof (Step), new PropertyMetadata(default(StepController)));

    public StepController Controller
    {
        get { return (StepController) GetValue(ControllerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControllerProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and your `StepController` class like that:

```
public class StepController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _stepEnabled;
    private bool? _wasSuccessful;

    public StepController()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    public bool StepEnabled
    {
        get { return _stepEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _stepEnabled) return;
            _stepEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool? WasSuccessful
    {
        get { return _wasSuccessful; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _wasSuccessful) return;
            _wasSuccessful = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        StepEnabled = false;
        WasSuccessful = null;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what are you trying to do with Controller="{Binding Path=Step1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}

First you created Controller as Dependency property later you are instantiating the same in step constructor . Since you are new your concept looks messed up seeing your code.
Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve so that we can help you? Just specify what you want in little clear English?

Answer (score 0):

Bindings will not work on fields.

Declare a property and rename your field

```
 public StepController Step1 { get { return _step1; } set { _step1 = value; }
```

Your exception is probably caused because your are using the "Controller" property without testing it for null.

Also, in your "Step" contructor you do

```
Controller = new StepController();
```

If your goal is to set a default value, complete your static DP declaration by

```
.... UIPropertyMetadata(new Controller()));
```